# Play! framework Java Promise example

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, promise, java-7

I'm reading up on Java's Play framework but don't have much experience in Java. Can someone please explain this

```
Promise<Double> promiseOfPIValue = computePIAsynchronously();
Promise<Result> promiseOfResult = promiseOfPIValue.map(
  new Function<Double,Result>() {
    public Result apply(Double pi) {
      return ok("PI value computed: " + pi);
    }
  }
);
```

I get that they're creating a promise `promiseOfPiValue` that's supposed to compute a double asynchronously. Then, they call `map` on that instance of promise to which they're passing a new instance of `Function` as an argument, which has implemented a the `apply` method.

The map part is where I get lost - how does the map method work? It looks like its returning a new promise of type `Result`, but what's the logic of calling the `apply` method inside an implementation of `Function`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From play documentation:

> Maps this promise to a promise of type `B`.  The function `function` is applied as soon as the promise is redeemed.

The function:

```
new Function<Double,Result>() {
    public Result apply(Double pi) {
      return ok("PI value computed: " + pi);
    }
}
```

will convert the `pi` value of type `Double` to `Result` using `ok()` function defined in `Controller` as soon as `computePIAsynchronously` is finished.

> but what's the logic of calling the apply method inside an implementation of Function?

This is the beauty of `Promises` and `Scala`. Scala promise framework will make sure the function is applied when promise is redeemed. If you want to read up on this topic, I suggest grabbing sources and documentation of `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext`.